# Wait until promise and nested thens are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery-deferred, promise

I'm returning a promise from a function like this:

```
resultPromise = dgps.utils.save(opportunity, '/api/Opportunity/Save', opportunity.dirtyFlag).then(function () {

                self.checklist.saveChecklist(opportunity).then(function () {

                    self.competitor.save(opportunity.selectedCompetitor()).then(function ... etc.
return resultPromise;
```

Let's say the above function is called save.

In the calling function I want to do wait for the entire chain to complete and then do something. My code there looks like this:

```
var savePromise = self.save();
savePromise.then(function() {
    console.log('aftersave');
});
```

The result is that 'aftersave' is send to the console while the chain of promises is still running.

How can I do something after the whole chain is complete?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of nesting the promises, chain them.

```
resultPromise = dgps.utils.save(opportunity, '/api/Opportunity/Save', opportunity.dirtyFlag).then(function () {

                    return self.checklist.saveChecklist(opportunity);
                }).then(function () {

                    return self.competitor.save(opportunity.selectedCompetitor());
                }).then(function () {
                    // etc
                });

// return a promise which completes when the entire chain completes
return resultPromise;
```

Comment: what if there's a conditional in there? Wouldn't you need the deferred object?

Comment: This is not the answer to question asked. The question was how to wait for chain to end. Simply adding more elements to the chain is not a solution and often won't work properly.

Comment: @MeanEYE You wait
t for the chain to end by doing a `then` on the chain. This solves the problem (though as you noted, it doesn't answer the literal question, but the question was really about a problem).