# WinJS Promise then erroring

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, winjs

After some experimentation, I've ended up with the following code, trying to replicate the C# await functionality:

```
var promise = new WinJS.Promise(MyFunc())
    .then(function () {
        // Second function which uses data set-up in the first
        MyFunc2();
    });
```

'MyFunc()' executes correctly, but 'MyFunc2()' does not, and the program crashes.  What am I misunderstanding about the Promise object?

(This is using Windows 8)

EDIT:

The full code for MyFunc() is now as follows:

```
function MyFunc() {
    var foldername = "Folder";
    var filename = "readme.xml";

    var promise = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFolderAsync(foldername).then(function (folder) {
        folder.getFileAsync(filename).then(function (file) {
            var loadSettings = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlLoadSettings;
            loadSettings.prohibitDtd = false;
            loadSettings.resolveExternals = false;
            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.loadFromFileAsync(file, loadSettings).then(function (doc) {
                dataText = doc.getXml();
                xmlDoc = doc;
            }, function (error) {
                output.value = "Error: Unable to load XML file";
                output.style.color = "red";
            }, function (error) {
                output.value = "Error: Unable to load XML file";
                output.style.color = "red";
            })
        })
    });

    return promise;
};
```

The result now is that 'MyFunc2()' executes before 'MyFunc()' completes.  `MyFunc2() uses the global variable xmlDoc, which is therefore undefined at that time.

Comment: Does MyFunc actually return the data you need? Or does it just set some global variables that need to be used in the function that comes after?

Comment: Just sets some global variables

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wait until promise and nested thens are complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173228/wait-until-promise-and-nested-thens-are-complete)

Comment: The parameter to `new WinJS.Promise` is not a promise. It's a promise-generator. Since you already have a promise, just use it directly. `var promise = MyFunc().then(...)`.

Comment: I don't understand why this is not what I'm already doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should chain all the promises together and then wait on the final promise.

```
function MyFunc() {
    var promise = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFolderAsync(foldername).then(function (folder) {
        return folder.getFileAsync(filename);
        }).done(function (file) {
            var loadSettings = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlLoadSettings;
            loadSettings.prohibitDtd = false;
            loadSettings.resolveExternals = false;
            return Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.loadFromFileAsync(file, loadSettings);
        }).then(function (doc) {
            dataText = doc.getXml();
            xmlDoc = doc;
            return doc; // whatever the result is
        }, function (error) {
            output.value = "Error: Unable to load XML file";
            output.style.color = "red";
        });
    return promise;
}
```

Then you can chain on the promise returned by `MyFunc`:

```
var promise = MyFunc().then(function(doc) { MyFunc2(...); });
```

Comment: I've edited my post to show the full code as it is now, although this still doesn't work.

Comment: This is sorted.  Your suggestion did work, however - you've got the done and then reversed.

Answer (score 1):

All right, given the edit, you will have to use a slightly different approach. You will need to make MyFunc() actually return the promise variable you are creating. This will allow you to chain `MyFunc` to `MyFunc2`. So you would do something like this:

```
var promise = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.current.installedLocation.getFolderAsync(foldername).then(function (folder) {
        folder.getFileAsync(filename).done(function (file) {
            var loadSettings = new Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlLoadSettings;
            loadSettings.prohibitDtd = false;
            loadSettings.resolveExternals = false;
            Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument.loadFromFileAsync(file, loadSettings).then(function (doc) {
                dataText = doc.getXml();
                xmlDoc = doc;
            }, function (error) {
                output.value = "Error: Unable to load XML file";
                output.style.color = "red";
            });
...
return promise;
```

Assuming that's the only promise in `MyFunc()`. If not, you can either chain all the promises together, or put them all in an array and return, for example, `WinJS.Promise.join(promiseArray)`.

Now that you are returning a promise from MyFunc(), you can use `then` to chain it.

```
var promise = MyFunc().then(function () {
    // Second function which uses data set-up in the first
    MyFunc2();
});
```

If `MyFunc2` also contains async code, you could return those promises as well, and keep chaining as long as you needed to.

```
var promise = MyFunc().then(function () {
    // Second function which uses data set-up in the first
    return MyFunc2();
}).then(function () {
    //And on and on...
});
```

Comment: See latest edit - MyFunc() does indeed contain asynchronous code.  Both of the approaches that you've suggested stop it crashing, but the second function begins before the first completes.

Comment: All right, I have modified my answer in light of the new information.

Comment: This still doesn't work.  Although it doesn't in MyFunc(), the code for MyFuncs2() is executes before it finishes.